# Web Application in Tomcat: reading from a DB works but nothing gets persisted?

Tags: java, database, tomcat

Has anyone ever encountered such a strange behaviour? My web application is able to access and read values from an Oracle database. I can verify that by connecting with a database tool, e.g. SqlDeveloper to the DB, change some value, then switch back to my web application and check that I can see the updated value there.

But if I am trying to write some value from the web application nothing gets persisted on the database. I can't see the updated value on the database. I have debugged until class

```
org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist
```

is invoked:

```
public void persist(Object entity) {
    checkTransactionNeeded();
    try {
        getSession().persist( entity );
    }
    catch ( MappingException e ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( e.getMessage() );
    }
    catch ( RuntimeException e ) {
        throw convert( e );
    }
}
```

No exception is thrown in this method but still nothing seems to arrive at the database. I've also checked the database trace logs but no error there either.
What kind of strange behaviour is this? Any ideas, hints, insights, etc.?

Comment: Crank up logging to DEBUG or TRACE level. Check what's happening on the DB side. With the information provided it's impossible to help; we know nothing about your system.

Comment: I already raised the log level to DEBUG, but as I wrote before... no exception, nothing. What do you mean exactly by "check what's happening on the DB side"? Because I checked the DB trace logs and no error there either.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your transaction handling?

It looks like you might not be commiting transaction - at thus all data you attempted to write is getting rollbacked/waiting for commit.

Comment: Shouldn't that be automatically covered by Hibernate? Or is there some configuration setting in Hibernate which prevents a commit?